# How to Show a corresponding element of the clicked element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I have multiple elements A,B,C,... And they are all "connected" to A1,B1,C1,...
For simplicity and better understanding , lets say A,B,C are personal data about A1,B1,C1 persons (A1,B1,C1 are pictures of those persons).

html looks like :

```
<div class="personal_data">
     <p class="A"> Ronnie </p>
     <p class="B"> James </p>
     <p class="C"> Dio </p>
</div>

<div class="persons">

 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="A1"> img1 </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="B1"> img2 </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="C1"> img3 </div>
  </div>
 </div> 

</div>
```

Yes , those `div`s that contain `img` are nested like that and the order **must not** be changed.
`p` elements are `hidden`and are shown in `personal_data` window according to which person has been clicked.
How can I make it that when one picture is clicked its corresponding `p` element is shown and the rest of them are hidden , and when I click to another picture it shows another `p` element and hides previous , and so on?

I tried with jQuery two methods :

```
$(".A1").click(function () {
         $(".A").show();
         $(".B").hide();
         $(".C").hide(); })
```

But I immediately abandoned it for obvious reasons. It's ugly and I have more than 3 persons so doing it for every person like this would not be a good practice.

```
$(".persons div").click(function () {
   var index=$(".persons div").index(this);
   $(".personal_data p").hide().eq(index).show(); })
```

Because I don't know `all` jQuery functions ( and all native javascript functions) I was amazed by the power of these but because of those nested images the `index` of A that corresponds to the A1 would be ok , but other indexes would not have their pair with `persons` because the number od `div`s are not equal , rather then "shifted" by +3. So I tweaked `.personal_data` with 2 empty `p` elements after A,B and C so the `index`es would align. And it worked but I feel like I am violating something .
Is there a more elegant way for achieving this? I feel my problem is lack of knowledge of all functions that exist inside javascript (and jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the list of matching clickable elements, and the personal data, ahead of time (so we don't have to keep re-querying them):

```
var clickables = $('.persons > div > div > div[class]');
var data = $('.personal_data p');
```

Then, when clicked, get the index of the clicked thing *in that list*, rather than hunt through the DOM:

```
clickables.click(
  function() {
    data.hide();                           // hide the others
    var idx = clickables.index(this);
    $(data[idx]).show();
  }
);
```

```js
var clickables = $('.persons > div > div > div[class]');
var data = $('.personal_data p');

clickables.click(
  function() {
    data.hide();
    var idx = clickables.index(this);
    $(data[idx]).show();
  }
)
```

```css
.personal_data p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="personal_data">
  <p class="A">Ronnie</p>
  <p class="B">James</p>
  <p class="C">Dio</p>
</div>

<div class="persons">

  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="A1">img1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="B1">img2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="C1">img3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you tell me what does the `div[class]` do?And what does it do "beneath the surface"? I never saw before this type of referring to an element. Does it somehow tracks only indexes of the elements with that `[class]`? I also tried it when all elements with "div[class]" have the same class (or id) , and it still works. Is that actually array of classes of nested divs?

Comment: Just a `div` with a `class` attribute, regardless of value. Just a reasonably-specific selector into that particular not-terribly-well-specified HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will have this class structure in your page consistently, I did something by comparing the class names. If the class name of the clicked div contains the class name of the `p` element, then the `p` will be shown, otherwise they will be hidden :

```
$(".persons div").click(function () {
   var myclassname = $(this).attr('class');

   $(".personal_data p").hide().filter(function() {
       return myclassname.indexOf($(this).attr('class')) >= 0); //if it contains
   }).show();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for providing different method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't like working with index's in lists. I prefer that you retrieve it when you mount it on the server-side with attributes and id's.

So try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.personal_data p').on('click', function (event) {
        var theTarget = $(this).attr('data-detail');
        $('.person-details').removeClass('show'); //remove this line in case you don't want only one at a time
        $('#' + theTarget).addClass('show');
    });

})
```

```css
.person-details {
        opacity: 0;
}

.person-details.show {
        opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="personal_data">
     <p class="A" data-detail="ronnie"> Ronnie </p>
     <p class="B" data-detail="james"> James </p>
     <p class="C" data-detail="dio"> Dio </p>
</div>

<div class="persons">

 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="A1 person-details" id="ronnie"> img1 </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="B1 person-details" id="james"> img2 </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="C1 person-details" id="dio"> img3 </div>
  </div>
 </div> 

</div>
```

All the styling or class you can customize. If you prefer showing or hiding , just change the removeClass to hide, and the addClass to show

If you want the oposite interaction :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.person-details').on('click', function (event) {
        var theTarget = $(this).attr('data-detail');
        $('.personal_data p').removeClass('show'); //remove this line in case you don't want only one at a time
        $('#' + theTarget).addClass('show');
    });

})
```

```css
.personal_data p {
        opacity: 0;
}

.personal_data p.show {
        opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="personal_data">
     <p class="A" id="ronnie"> Ronnie </p>
     <p class="B" id="james"> James </p>
     <p class="C" id="dio"> Dio </p>
</div>

<div class="persons">

 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="A1 person-details" data-detail="ronnie"> img1 </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="B1 person-details" data-detail="james" > img2 </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div>
  <div>
   <div class="C1 person-details" data-detail="dio"> img3 </div>
  </div>
 </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: I feel awkward when I do not reply to people who wanted to help even if It's against the rules to say thanks. :) I appreciate different method you provided.